# How do you stop, take offline, and delete a SQL Server database in recovery?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a development database which has entered recovery mode on restart, and has been recovering for the last hour or so.

I need to either stop the recovery, or kill it in some way.

I don't care one bit about the database or any of the data, I have deployment scripts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

- Stop SQL Server
- Delete MDF + LDF
- Start SQL Server
- Restore (may need to drop first, comes up suspect)

If the MDF and LDF are present on service start up, it will go into rollforward/rollback recovery. You have to drop them to prevent this.

Comment: What if you can't stop sql server because of other databases that shouldn't go down? There is no other way?

Comment: @ErikDekker Probably too late to be of help, but you can also just detach the database

Comment: This was perfect advice for my situation.  Dummy/dev-testing instance, database restore was interrupted midway, had to completely kill it and remove it before attempting a fresh restore.  The bit "need to drop first" was the trick -- after you stop SQL service, delete the files, and start SQL service, the DB *will* still be listed in the object-explorer, but simply right-click-"Delete" (aka Drop) will finish it off.  Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that you cannot detach a database stuck in the restoring state. Nor can you detach it.

Comment: For me, with a database in "Recovery Pending" and a server low on disk space (the likely cause of the "pending"), stopping SQL Server, deleting the mdf and ldf, then a restart was the only way forward.  Using Detach Database would not work for me with a database in recovery pending state.

Comment: I was unable to stop the database from the Management Studio or Services, but Task Manager was able to kill the process.

Answer (score 8):

1. Right click on the database in SQL Server Management Studio, and hit Detach.
2. Select the Drop Connections checkbox only, and hit ok.
3. Then the database will disappear.
4. Right click on the Databases folder, and click Attach...
5. Click Add and find the .mdf file for the database you deleted.  You will have to find it in the file system.
6. Click Ok, and it will be back online.