# How to recover if SQL Server is stuck in Restoring state?

Tags: sql-server, restore

My demo server went down and database is now stuck in **Restoring mode**. I tried to bring it back with

```
RESTORE DATABASE DB_Name 
WITH RECOVERY, REPLACE
```

but it throws an error:

> Msg 4333, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The database cannot be recovered because the log was not restored.

Then I tried to restore the log files from local drive

```
RESTORE LOG DB_Name 
FROM Disk = 'H:\Log\DB_Name_log' 
WITH RECOVERY;  
GO
```

Again I got an error

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
>   Cannot open backup device 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\H:\Log DB_Name_log'.
>   Operating system error 123 (the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.)

I did reboot multiple times no use of it. How can I bring back my database to normal state from restoring mode?

I tried with the suggestion provided in below link it's not working for me. [SQL server databases stuck in restoring state](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56169/sql-server-databases-stuck-in-restoring-state)

Comment: You have an extra slash in your RESTORE LOG command before the \H:. Try removing it and running the restore again. Also usually the log file will have an .ldf extension, which you should probably include. Also, if it's your demo database, do you need recovery?

Comment: @JacobH, I tried as you suggested but no progress still database in Recovery pending state. Yes, If it is any DB I want this to up and running.

Comment: Can you update the question with  new syntax that you are running?

Comment: `H:\Log\DB_Name_log` where is the extension of the logfile?

Comment: I was talking about `RECOVERY` vs `NORECOVERY`. You should restore the log files with NORECOVERY, then the DB with RECOVERY. Did the log get successfully restored when you ran the updated query? You should probably update the post with your most recent attempts and results.