# I just exited SSMS while restoring a UAT database, am I screwed?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just flinched and closed out of habit while waiting for the restore to reach 100%. Did I just break everything? Is it possible to view the progress of the restore?

Update:  I was in a bit of a panic, so I roped in my team lead. The database was now [stuck in the restoring state](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56169/sql-server-databases-stuck-in-restoring-state) and that script didn't work so we just dropped it and started over. It went *okay*.

Was that necessary? In the UI for a restore there is a period of time before the percentage complete is displayed. I had closed the application before that... not sure if that matters.

Comment: Do you mean that you killed the connection running the restore command?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 4):

This is baked into [sp_Whoisactive](http://www.whoisactive.com) as well without needing an ad-hoc script.

It's the percent_complete column, over to the right (removed some superflous columns like sql_text and waitinfo):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The backup will continue to run to completion.

This code will tell you an approximate time to completion of the backup.

```
SELECT command,
        s.text,
        start_time,
        percent_complete,
        CAST(((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate()))/3600) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
              + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%3600)/60 as varchar) + 'min, '
              + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%60) as varchar) + ' sec' as running_time,
        CAST((estimated_completion_time/3600000) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
              + CAST((estimated_completion_time %3600000)/60000 as varchar) + 'min, '
              + CAST((estimated_completion_time %60000)/1000 as varchar) + ' sec' as est_time_to_go,
        dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as est_completion_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s
WHERE r.command in ('RESTORE DATABASE', 'BACKUP DATABASE', 'RESTORE LOG', 'BACKUP LOG')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT session_id as SPID, command, a.text AS Query, start_time, percent_complete, dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time  
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a  
WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')
```

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server/