# Source Database of a restore stuck Restoring

Tags: sql-server, restore, ssms

I have copied a database vn_Budget_2021_BofDOct29 to the database vn_Budget_2021_Rig2. I did this through Tasks->Restore Database shown in the second image.

I saw this similar issue except the database I've restored isn't the one hanging. Its my source DB that doesn't require any restoring in iteslf.
[SQL server databases stuck in restoring state](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56169/sql-server-databases-stuck-in-restoring-state)

How do I get it stop hanging? I don't need to restore this database to the same name. The last backup is a few days old and theres nothing wrong with the data.

[image: Restore to Rig2 successful]

Method of restoring. No logs were taken which may be the issue?
[image: restored through Tasks]

Comment: Was the database in a "restoring" state before you did this ?

Comment: Hi Dominique, no it was not!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can happen when you don't uncheck in the GUI to take a tail-log backup.

It is a nasty behavior by the GUI. You type a new database name in the restore GUI, the one to be created by the RESTORE command. But the GUI still does a tail-log backup of the source database, and it does it by default using the NORECOVERY option (which s precicely what puts the source db in restoring state).

The image you posted doesn't reflect this, so I can deduce that it wasn't the actual screen from your restore. You would have a note in the upper left of the dialog.

So, in the future, go to the Options page and uncheck the tail log backup when you restore into a new database name.

To handle the immediate situation, you just execute below (obviously substituting the database name):

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbname WITH RECOVERY
```

No backup files needed.